# AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'TunerInternal._validate_overwrite_trainable' on <module 'ray.tune.impl.tuner_internal'

Tags: ray, database-tuning

When I am trying to run a Basic Ray Model in our server, Tune Code is breaking. I didnt understand the issue and I didnt find any useful information in internet. Can any one help me with it. FYI, I am able to run them properly when I use local ray cluster which I setup in my local machine.

AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'TunerInternal._validate_overwrite_trainable' on <module 'ray.tune.impl.tuner_internal' from '/home/ray/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ray/tune/impl/tuner_internal.py'>

```
import ray
from ray.air.config import ScalingConfig
from ray.train.xgboost import XGBoostTrainer

trainer = XGBoostTrainer(
    scaling_config=ScalingConfig(
        # Number of workers to use for data parallelism.
        num_workers=2,
        # Whether to use GPU acceleration.
        use_gpu=False,
    ),
    label_column="y",
    num_boost_round=20,
    params={
        # XGBoost specific params
        "objective": "binary:logistic",
        # "tree_method": "gpu_hist",  # uncomment this to use GPUs.
        "eval_metric": ["logloss", "error"],
    },
    datasets={"train": traindata_ray},
   # preprocessor=preprocessor,
)
result = trainer.fit()
print(result.metrics)
```

Reference: https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/train/train.html

Comment: Can you try just uninstalling and reinstalling Ray?

Comment: I tried it but didn't resolve the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely due to a `ray` version mismatch.  `_validate_overwrite_trainable` is available in nightly wheels but not in the latest `2.2.0` release.

Can you verify that you are using the same version of `ray` across your local machine and cluster?

Comment: Thanks for the help. As you mentioned, there was Ray package mismatch. my server version is Ray 2.1 while I am using 2.2 After I requested my admin to upgrade the ray package, error was resolved.